# How to creat a Qlabel drop down and QEditLineText in a single Row?

Tags: qt4

I am new in Qt Development. I need your help for developing multiple row in a screen and each row will contain Qlabel drop down and QEditLineText. Row will be generated dynamically and screen will be scrollable vertically.

Can you please give me a sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt provides numerous examples for its various modules (refer to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/all-examples.html).  If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to create a table containing editable items, in which case you will want to pay particular attention to the [Item Views examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-itemviews.html) (sample code is included).

If you are new to Qt Development, you'll save yourself a lot of time if you go through at least the essential [Qt Tutorials](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tutorials.html).  In your case, the [Model/View Tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html) is particularly important.